# Fixing Date formats in SQL

Tags: python, sql, datetime

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
       "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
       "Trade Details 2".START_DATE, 
       "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 
       "Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
       "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV,
       "Trade Details".TERM
FROM "Trade Details 2" 
JOIN "Trade Details" 
WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID and
      ("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") and
      ("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > "20180621")

ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID asc
```

I'm attempting to fix the date formats for my `START_DATE` and `MATURITY_DATE` columns in the tables I've joined in this query. The format for the `START_DATE` is like: `2018-06-22 00:00:00`, while the `MATURITY_DATE` is like: `20180622`. I would like to be able to fix this so both columns are the same format, preferably just `2018-06-22`. I have already tried in python using:
    input_string='20191217'

```
start_date=pd.to_datetime(input_string[-2:]+input_string[4:6]+ 
input_string[:4], dayfirst=True)
```

but that didn't work, just claiming invalid syntax. Is there a way in SQL or Python to make these two columns have the same date?

Comment: which database product are you using?

Comment: DB Browser for SQL, if I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

What DBMS are you using ?
You need to convert your start date by using `STR_TO_DATE('your string', '%Y-%m-%d')` for example.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2018-06-22', '%Y-%m-%d') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: hmmm, that doesn't seem to have worked. In place of DUAL, do I need the actual table names, or something, because it's not turning any of the START or MATURITY dates to having the same format

Comment: DUAL is a dummy table just use STR_TO_DATE('2018-06-22', '%Y-%m-%d') to replace START_DATE

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed query for SQLite DB

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
       "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
       DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
       DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||    substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE, 
       "Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
       "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV,
       "Trade Details".TERM
FROM "Trade Details 2" 
JOIN "Trade Details" 
WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID and
      ("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") and
      ("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > DATE(substr('20180602', 0, 5) || '-' || substr('20180602', 5,2) || '-' ||    substr('20180602', 7, 9)) )

ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID asc
```

Comment: `SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, "Trade Details 2".START_DATE, "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, "Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1, "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV, "Trade Details".TERM
FROM "Trade Details 2" 
JOIN "Trade Details" 
WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID and
("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") and
("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > "20180621") and
(select date('2018-06-22 00:00:00') as START_DATE,
       date('20180622') as MATURITY_DATE )

ORDER BY "Trade Details 2".Portfolio asc`  Updated but it didn't work, syntax?

Comment: @throway172 I updated the query, so that it will work for SQLite

Comment: still saying sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1

Comment: I changed the query, please try

Comment: Yeah, it's claiming there's a syntax error near "as" although I've checkd all paranthesis and everything. SQL error messages are not very helpful

Comment: @throway172 sorry my bad, I had a typo. Please check now